# Why doesn't this code work? Guess the number game Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm trying to write a code where the computer guesses the number the user thinks of. I used a range between (x,y) and gave x and y the values of 0 and 10.

The computer chooses a random number between these and than asks if than number is correct, if it isn't than it asks if it's higher or lower.

Here comes the tricky part, or actually just the way I wanted to solve it. If the user says it's a higher number, then it sets `x` to be the guess number, and loops back to the guessing part, and goes again, if it's lower, `y` is set to be the guess.

This is the code I've written for that:

```
import random
x = 0
y = 10
guessing_loop = "y"
no_guess = 0

while guessing_loop == "y":
    guess = random.randint(x - 1,y + 1)
    no_guess = no_guess + 1
    print("The number I think you thought of is",guess,".")
    TF = input("Did you think of that number?")
    if TF in {"yes","y","yeah"}:
        print("Hell yeah, the number of guesses I had was:",no_guess,".")
    elif TF in{"no","nah","nay","n","nope"}:
        HL = input("Then was it a higher or a lower number?")
        if HL in {"higher","h"}:
            x = guess
        elif HL in {"lower","l"}:
            y = guess

input()
```

Why doesn't this code work?

This code simply does not do what I expect it to do, it doesn't look for a random number between the guesses or I'm not even sure what is wrong.

Comment: People are downvoting this and voting-to-close it; you need to show more effort to debug your own code: put in as many print statements as you need to follow what it's actually doing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I really do appreciate these advices. I'm new to both programming and this community and I'm still trying to fit, I don't wanna annoy anyone. I will put more print statements in every code from now on.

Comment: Sure. Welcome to Python and also to SO. Please give a brief skim to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and browse some other few beginner Python questions to see good tips on how to ask your question here to get the best response. Also you might like [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) for general code-reviews as opposed to specific questions with well-defined objective answers.

Comment: Also, don't call the response variable `TF` (upper-case not allowed in variable names), call it e.g. `response` or `correct` or something. Python has a well-defined style guide called [PEP-8](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PEP-8). Posters are generally expected to follow it. And similarly `HL` -> `higher_lower`.

Comment: @smci "Why doesn't this code work?" questions are off-topic on Code Review. Please read [Be careful when recommending Code Review to askers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: but I never said Code Review was for "Why doesn't this code work?" questions. I said it was for code reviews. And I directed them to the FAQs.

Comment: @smci Simon was simply pointing out that *this* question is very much so a "Why doesn't this code work?" question, so it's probably not the best question to be pointing a new user toward Code Review for.

Comment: And I never referred this question to Code Review. I told them to read the FAQ, and also that Code Review is a separate site for a different purpose. This question had already been answered here, so there was very little chance they would both misunderstand and go repost it there, of all places. I will take care not to give any impression to the contrary, ok?

Comment: @smci Sorry, apparently I misunderstood what you were trying to say then.

Comment: @smci Thank you very much, I checked put the CodeReview website and I will keep in mind what you said about variables and capital letters, thanks for improving my Python. If it feels like I'm just simply dumb in it, that's because I just turned 16 and I am. :D

Comment: No problems, just keep learning and reading.

Answer (score 3):

Several issues:

- You're not breaking out of the loop once you found the correct number.
- Use variable names that show what they mean, e.g. `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` instead of `x` and `y`.
- Instead of `random.randint(x - 1,y + 1)`, you want `random.randint(x + 1,y - 1)`